# Starting an app when the screen is locked?

Tags: lock-screens, automation

Is there any easy way to start an app when you press the button to lock your screen? I've seen custom lock screens before so I know it's possible even if I have to make my own app for it. I have an app that I want to pop up every time the screen is unlocked, but it doesn't do it on it's own. I've seen/used other apps that could do this so if necessary I would code my own app to do this, but I'd prefer an already existing, preferably free option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be multiple solutions to this. One I can think of involves the use of [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), the most flexible automation tool for Android. You could create a profile that triggers on "Screen Unlock", and have it start an app.

However: though there's a free 7 day trial available on the projects homepage, after that the app costs about 5 Euro. There are many other automation apps available on the playstore which might be able to achieve the same. As a long-time *Tasker* user I no longer try the others, so I cannot tell for sure.

**Condition:** Event → Display → Display Unlocked
**Task:** App → Load App → (select your app here)

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up getting AutomateIt because it's free and works just as good for my purposes. If you hadn't mentioned tasker I might never have found AutomateIt :D

Comment: Glad it helped! There are a lot of automation apps out there, hard to keep all their features and limitations in mind. Luckily there's almost always one fitting the purposes of the questioner :)